# Web Banner ad design choices

Tags: website-design, adobe-edge-animate

It's been awhile since I have designed an animated web banner ad - I used to design them in flash, but that is not really used anymore. What programs do you recommend to design animated banners now and what's the best format to deliver them in?

Right now I have Adobe Edge Animate and I was planning on delivering it in HTML 5.  I suppose I could also use Google web designer. Any pros and cons to these? Other preferences? Is HTML 5 the best format?

Thanks!

Comment: Both work great. HTML 5 is the way to go!

Comment: Quote:     "2016 Across all ad formats and placements Ad CTR is 0.17%
So, this is less than 2 clicks per 1000 impressions showing the difficulty of driving response from online ads. "  Banner ads are the work of the devil and dismissed by most regular web users, most often with a blocking plugin these days. Google's lack of control and Wild West approach to use is at the root of this. Advise your client to try something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Google Web Designer. The learning curve isn't too steep and the results are good.

I'd give Adobe Animate CC a go for more complex tasks and animations.

As Zach Saucier mentioned - HTML 5 is the way to go these days!

Comment: What aspects of Google Web Designer do you like? Why is Animate better for complex animations? This answer could benefit from a bit more detail

Answer (score -2):

If it's simply an animated GIF, I still use Photoshop (with Animation Timeline on). Have been doing this for over 20 years.

Comment: Why do you use this over other tools? What benefits does PS have that the other tools mentioned do not? What about when it's not a gif?

Comment: I could tell you the benefits if I were an expert in the other tools. But I haven't installed nor worked with those other apps yet. I'm just an old dog with old tricks.

Comment: Yes, but you can probably tell why this tool works for you. Some pros and cons that you see in your 20 years working with it would improve the quality of your answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think for creating animated HTML5 ads, Adobe Animate CC is one of the best bet for production and  HTML5 Banners, for both creating advertising, simple and complex animations or motion design.  The program itself is smoother and makes the entire workflow faster.

Answer (score -3):

This link will send to a google page that talks about Googles Web designer for ads reccomend using it since they will have it up to date on their latest changes  [HERE](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/3261498?hl=en&ref_topic=3261495)